# ScrollView not working inside layout

Tags: android, android-layout

what my problem is when user come on this screen it should be scroll the screen but some how its not scrolling? so this is my xml code which has scroll view inside CoordinatorLayout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:background="@color/main_background_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_top_padding">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MaxxSports.ToolbarTextAppearance"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:elevation="2dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/al_svMainScroll"
            android:layout_below="@id/appbar_layout"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lf_cvInputContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lf_firstNameInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:minHeight="72dp"
                        android:theme="@style/MaxxSports.TextInputLayout">
                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            style="@style/MaxxSports.EditTextStyle"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lf_lastNameInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:minHeight="72dp"
                        android:theme="@style/MaxxSports.TextInputLayout">
                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            style="@style/MaxxSports.EditTextStyle"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lf_emailInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:minHeight="72dp"
                        android:theme="@style/MaxxSports.TextInputLayout">
                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            style="@style/MaxxSports.EditTextStyle"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lf_passwordInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:minHeight="72dp"
                        android:theme="@style/MaxxSports.TextInputLayout">
                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            style="@style/MaxxSports.EditTextStyle"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lf_confirmPasswordInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:minHeight="72dp"
                        android:theme="@style/MaxxSports.TextInputLayout">
                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            style="@style/MaxxSports.EditTextStyle"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>-->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/lf_createAccountButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/lf_cvInputContainer"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/sign_in_btn_bg"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Create Account"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

so after trying so many things and work around still not found a solution ,any suggestion or where i was wrong please tell me.

Comment: I tested this code and it works for me.

Comment: but its not working in most of the device....on which device have you tested?

Comment: Lenovo Moto G5 android 7.1, but obviously I had to change theme to default.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="2dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/al_svMainScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar_layout"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lf_cvInputContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lf_firstNameInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:minHeight="72dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lf_lastNameInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:minHeight="72dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lf_emailInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:minHeight="72dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lf_passwordInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:minHeight="72dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lf_confirmPasswordInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:minHeight="72dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <!--</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>-->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lf_createAccountButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/lf_cvInputContainer"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Create Account"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment.i have already try that but still not working.

Comment: @umeshvashisth did u try with hight=`match_parent` in your scrollview

Comment: @umeshvashisth also `hight=match_parent` of relative layout

Comment: @umeshvashisth check updated ans its woking fine in my device

Comment: the child of a scrollview must not have match_parent for height

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks for notifying me the above code is also working with `wrap_content` hight of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: if the child of a scrollview has match_parent as height, there is nothing to scroll. It can only work with wrap_content

Comment: @NileshRathod thanks for your ans ...i have found that some how its not work with fragment and if i use activity than its work perfectly.but some how i don't understand why its not work with fragment xml.thanks

Comment: @umeshvashisth than you need to add scollview inside fragment layout

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NestedScrollView` while working with `CoordinatorLayout`.. and you are utilising layout behaviour of `CoordinatorLayout`. Like below..

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ....
    ...>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        ....>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/al_svMainScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- Your scrollring layout will go here -->

    </NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```